# Game Scoring returns NaN, No luck with +=

Tags: javascript, operators, nan

I'm going to do my best to describe my problem here. My js code is supposed to assign a value to the hand and chip variable from an if statement. This is then passed to another function which applies a multiplier to it based off of a coin flip. At the end, it should write the results to the page, and keep the total count of the score while resetting the hand each time.

I believe my problem is when i try to do `var totalHand = (totalHand + handC);`, which returns NaN. Im stuck as to where to go next, my teacher had mentioned using parseInt but I'm not sure that would solve the problem, or how to apply it.

https://jsfiddle.net/armadadamra/swcL1d2m/7/

I appreciate any help and ask for some patience, i'm only in my first semester of learning js. Thanks

Where I think the problem is:

```
var totalHand = (totalHand + handC);

var greenChipTotal = (greenChipTotal + greenCC);
var redChipTotal = (redChipTotal + redCC);
var purpleChipTotal = (purpleChipTotal + purpleCC);
var blackChipTotal = (blackChipTotal +  blackCC);
```

All the js:

```
// images
var dice1 = ['<img src="images/dice1.png" name="diceOne" width="250" height="250">']
var dice2 = ['<img src="images/dice2.png" name="diceTwo" width="250" height="250">']
var dice3 = ['<img src="images/dice3.png" name="diceThree" width="250" height="250">']
var dice4 = ['<img src="images/dice4.png" name="diceFour" width="250" height="250">']
var dice5 = ['<img src="images/dice5.png" name="diceFive" width="250" height="250">']
var dice6 = ['<img src="images/dice6.png" name="diceSix" width="250" height="250">']
var loader = ['<img src="images/loading.gif" name="load" width="250" height="250">']
var coin1 = ['<img src="images/coin1.jpg" name="coinOne" width="250" height="250">']
var coin2 = ['<img src="images/coin2.jpg" name="coinTwo" width="250" height="250">']
// game vars
var totalA = 0;
var handA = 0;
var greenC = 0;
var redC = 0;
var purpleC = 0;
var blackC = 0;

function myRandoms() {
var ranA = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
var ranB = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
var ranC = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);    
var ranD = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
// dice display
// dice a
if (ranA==1){document.getElementById("tdDiceA").innerHTML = dice1;};
if (ranA==2){document.getElementById("tdDiceA").innerHTML = dice2;};
if (ranA==3){document.getElementById("tdDiceA").innerHTML = dice3;};
if (ranA==4){document.getElementById("tdDiceA").innerHTML = dice4;};
if (ranA==5){document.getElementById("tdDiceA").innerHTML = dice5;};
if (ranA==6){document.getElementById("tdDiceA").innerHTML = dice6;};
// dice b
if (ranB==1){document.getElementById("tdDiceB").innerHTML = dice1;};
if (ranB==2){document.getElementById("tdDiceB").innerHTML = dice2;};
if (ranB==3){document.getElementById("tdDiceB").innerHTML = dice3;};
if (ranB==4){document.getElementById("tdDiceB").innerHTML = dice4;};
if (ranB==5){document.getElementById("tdDiceB").innerHTML = dice5;};
if (ranB==6){document.getElementById("tdDiceB").innerHTML = dice6;};
// dice c
if (ranC==1){document.getElementById("tdDiceC").innerHTML = dice1;};
if (ranC==2){document.getElementById("tdDiceC").innerHTML = dice2;};
if (ranC==3){document.getElementById("tdDiceC").innerHTML = dice3;};
if (ranC==4){document.getElementById("tdDiceC").innerHTML = dice4;};
if (ranC==5){document.getElementById("tdDiceC").innerHTML = dice5;};
if (ranC==6){document.getElementById("tdDiceC").innerHTML = dice6;};
// dice d
if (ranD==1){document.getElementById("tdDiceD").innerHTML = dice1;};
if (ranD==2){document.getElementById("tdDiceD").innerHTML = dice2;};
if (ranD==3){document.getElementById("tdDiceD").innerHTML = dice3;};
if (ranD==4){document.getElementById("tdDiceD").innerHTML = dice4;};
if (ranD==5){document.getElementById("tdDiceD").innerHTML = dice5;};
if (ranD==6){document.getElementById("tdDiceD").innerHTML = dice6;};
//resets checkboxes, coin picture and saying
$( "#checkHeads" ).prop( "checked", false );
$( "#checkTails" ).prop( "checked", false );
$( "#checkSkip" ).prop( "checked", false );
document.getElementById("tdCoin").innerHTML = loader;
document.getElementById("tr2td7").innerHTML = "";

// scoring
// four in a row
if (ranA==1 && ranB==1 && ranC==1 && ranD==1) {handA=100; blackC=1};
if (ranA==2 && ranB==2 && ranC==2 && ranD==2) {handA=100; blackC=1};
if (ranA==3 && ranB==3 && ranC==3 && ranD==3) {handA=100; blackC=1};
if (ranA==4 && ranB==4 && ranC==4 && ranD==4) {handA=100; blackC=1};
if (ranA==5 && ranB==5 && ranC==5 && ranD==5) {handA=100; blackC=1};
if (ranA==6 && ranB==6 && ranC==6 && ranD==6) {handA=100; blackC=1};
//three in a row
//1
if (ranA==1 && ranB==1 && ranC==1) {handA=50; purpleC=1};
if (ranB==1 && ranC==1 && ranD==1) {handA=50; purpleC=1};
//2
if (ranA==2 && ranB==2 && ranC==2) {handA=50; purpleC=1};
if (ranB==2 && ranC==2 && ranD==2) {handA=50; purpleC=1};
//3
if (ranA==3 && ranB==3 && ranC==3) {handA=50; purpleC=1};
if (ranB==3 && ranC==3 && ranD==3) {handA=50; purpleC=1};
//4
if (ranA==4 && ranB==4 && ranC==4) {handA=50; purpleC=1};
if (ranB==4 && ranC==4 && ranD==4) {handA=50; purpleC=1};
//5
if (ranA==5 && ranB==5 && ranC==5) {handA=50; purpleC=1};
if (ranB==5 && ranC==5 && ranD==5) {handA=50; purpleC=1};
//6
if (ranA==6 && ranB==6 && ranC==6) {handA=50; purpleC=1};
if (ranB==6 && ranC==6 && ranD==6) {handA=50; purpleC=1};
//straights
if (ranA==1 && ranB==2 && ranC==3 && ranD==4) {handA=20; redC=1};
if (ranA==2 && ranB==3 && ranC==4 && ranD==5) {handA=20; redC=1};
if (ranA==3 && ranB==4 && ranC==5 && ranD==6) {handA=20; redC=1};
if (ranA==6 && ranB==5 && ranC==4 && ranD==3) {handA=20; redC=1};
if (ranA==5 && ranB==4 && ranC==3 && ranD==2) {handA=20; redC=1};
if (ranA==4 && ranB==3 && ranC==2 && ranD==1) {handA=20; redC=1};
//pairs
//1
if (ranA==1 && ranB==1) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranA==1 && ranC==1) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranA==1 && ranD==1) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranB==1 && ranC==1) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranB==1 && ranD==1) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranC==1 && ranD==1) {handA=5; greenC=1};
//2
if (ranA==2 && ranB==2) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranA==2 && ranC==2) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranA==2 && ranD==2) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranB==2 && ranC==2) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranB==2 && ranD==2) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranC==2 && ranD==2) {handA=5; greenC=1};
//3
if (ranA==3 && ranB==3) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranA==3 && ranC==3) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranA==3 && ranD==3) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranB==3 && ranC==3) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranB==3 && ranD==3) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranC==3 && ranD==3) {handA=5; greenC=1};
//4
if (ranA==4 && ranB==4) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranA==4 && ranC==4) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranA==4 && ranD==4) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranB==4 && ranC==4) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranB==4 && ranD==4) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranC==4 && ranD==4) {handA=5; greenC=1};
//5
if (ranA==5 && ranB==5) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranA==5 && ranC==5) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranA==5 && ranD==5) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranB==5 && ranC==5) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranB==5 && ranD==5) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranC==5 && ranD==5) {handA=5; greenC=1};
//6
if (ranA==6 && ranB==6) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranA==6 && ranC==6) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranA==6 && ranD==6) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranB==6 && ranC==6) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranB==6 && ranD==6) {handA=5; greenC=1};
if (ranC==6 && ranD==6) {handA=5; greenC=1};
}

function randomCoin() {
var handB = handA;
var greenCB = greenC;
var redCB = redC;
var purpleCB = purpleC;
var blackCB = blackC;

alert(" hand "+handB+" green "+greenCB+" red "+redCB+" purple "+purpleCB+" black "+blackCB);

var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
// coin display
if (random==1){document.getElementById("tdCoin").innerHTML = coin1;};
if (random==2){document.getElementById("tdCoin").innerHTML = coin2;};
// heads true
if (random==1 && $('#checkHeads').is(':checked')){
    document.getElementById("tr2td7").innerHTML = "<h2>Win!</h2>";

    var handC = handB * 2;
    var greenCC = greenCB * 2;
    var redCC = redCB * 2;
    var purpleCC = purpleCB * 2;
    var blackCC = blackCB * 2;
}
// tails true
if (random==2 && $('#checkTails').is(':checked')){
    document.getElementById("tr2td7").innerHTML = "<h2>Win!</h2>";

    var handC = handB * 2;
    var greenCC = greenCB * 2;
    var redCC = redCB * 2;
    var purpleCC = purpleCB * 2;
    var blackCC = blackCB * 2;
}
// heads false
if (random==1 && $('#checkTails').is(':checked')){
    document.getElementById("tr2td7").innerHTML = "<h2>False.</h2>";

    var handC = handB * 0;
    var greenCC = greenCB * 0;
    var redCC = redCB * 0;
    var purpleCC = purpleCB * 0;
    var blackCC = blackCB * 0;
}
// tails false
if (random==2 && $('#checkHeads').is(':checked')){
    document.getElementById("tr2td7").innerHTML = "<h2>False.</h2>";

    var handC = handB * 0;
    var greenCC = greenCB * 0;
    var redCC = redCB * 0;
    var purpleCC = purpleCB * 0;
    var blackCC = blackCB * 0;
}
// skip
if ($('#checkSkip').is(':checked')){
    {document.getElementById("tdCoin").innerHTML = loader;};

    var handC = handB * 1;
    var greenCC = greenCB * 1;
    var redCC = redCB * 1;
    var purpleCC = purpleCB * 1;
    var blackCC = blackCB * 1;
}

alert(" hand "+handB+" green "+greenCB+" red "+redCB+" purple "+purpleCB+" black "+blackCB);
alert(" hand "+handC+" green "+greenCC+" red "+redCC+" purple "+purpleCC+" black "+blackCC);


var totalHand = (totalHand + handC);

var greenChipTotal = (greenChipTotal + greenCC);
var redChipTotal = (redChipTotal + redCC);
var purpleChipTotal = (purpleChipTotal + purpleCC);
var blackChipTotal = (blackChipTotal +  blackCC);

document.getElementById("gameTotal").innerHTML = "Total: " + totalHand;
document.getElementById("gameHand").innerHTML = "Hand: " + handC;

document.getElementById("chip5").innerHTML = greenChipTotal;
document.getElementById("chip20").innerHTML = redChipTotal;
document.getElementById("chip50").innerHTML = purpleChipTotal;
document.getElementById("chip100").innerHTML = blackChipTotal;

if (totalHand.value == 100) {alert("Winner Winner Chick Dinner!!!");};
}

function resetGame(){
// sets dice to loader
document.getElementById("tdDiceA").innerHTML = loader;
document.getElementById("tdDiceB").innerHTML = loader;
document.getElementById("tdDiceC").innerHTML = loader;
document.getElementById("tdDiceD").innerHTML = loader;
//resets checkboxes, coin picture and saying
$( "#checkHeads" ).prop( "checked", false );
$( "#checkTails" ).prop( "checked", false );
$( "#checkSkip" ).prop( "checked", false );
document.getElementById("tdCoin").innerHTML = loader;
document.getElementById("tr2td7").innerHTML = "";

//clears game info
document.getElementById("gameTotal").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("gameHand").innerHTML = "";

document.getElementById("chip5").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("chip20").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("chip50").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("chip100").innerHTML = "";

var totalHand = 0;
var handb = 0;

var greenChipTotal = 0;
var redChipTotal = 0;
var purpleChipTotal = 0;
var blackChipTotal =  0;

var handB = 0;
var greenCB = 0;
var redCB = 0;
var purpleCB = 0;
var blackCB = 0;
}
```

Comment: Pls add the relevant code into your question.

Comment: A fiddle is nice, but please copy the relevant code directly into your question.

Comment: The code isn't on this page probably because it is so long that the OP does not know where the relevant part is. In the fiddle, you have `var totalHand = (totalHand = handC);` even when I change it to + it still doe not run

Comment: Give me a second, I'm putting the code in now

Comment: Yes @Huangism thats the problem i've been having and am looking for a solution

Comment: Please describe what is needed to reproduce this issue. When I look at this fiddle, I see a bunch of missing images or something and I have no idea how to produce the error

Comment: Why are you using the variable within the variable declaration?

Comment: `var totalHand = (totalHand + handC);` I don't think you defined totalhand before using it

Comment: @Huangism Just click the button that says start game, then click the radio button that says skip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because totalHand was not initialized before you tried to add handC. Since it's not initialized, it is essentially null. Therefore, your statement reads "Add the value of handC to null, and store the value in variable totalHand". As you can probably guess, you can't add an integer to null.

You should be able fix this by replacing your code with the following.

```
var totalHand = 0;
```

Add this inside your function.

```
totalHand += handC;
```

This will set totalHand to zero instead of null.

Edit: To keep a total of the score, you will need another variable. Add this after you calculate totalHand.

```
var totalScore = 0;
```

Add this inside your function.

```
totalScore += totalHand;
```

Comment: Thank You, but how do I go about keeping that as a running total of the score?

Comment: I'll edit the question. I think I know what you want, but if I'm wrong, point it out to me.

Comment: But as long as you have =0 , won't it set equal to zero every time the function is ran? I need it to accumulate the value of handC over time.

Comment: Declare the variable outside of the function. My bad. I should have clarified that in the question.